# How should a mysql alias be accessed?

Tags: mysql

Given that this is defined in a mysql script:

```
`Project1`.`Id` AS `Id1d334656-0d51-4bf6-bb08-6c25d01e7745`
```

Does this mean that

```
`Project1`.`Id`
```

is no longer accessible by that name and only by

```
`Project1`.`Id1d334656-0d51-4bf6-bb08-6c25d01e7745`
```

?

Background: This script is being generated by MySqlConnector/net and this is part of the command that is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aliases have no table assignment, so it'd be just `ID1d3346etc....`. If they did, that'd defeat the purpose of the aliases, e.g.

```
select table1.x AS abc, table2.x AS abc
```

would be an error, even though the two aliases are coming from different tables.

Comment: If only one of those were defined, `select table1.x AS abc`, and then later, an attempt to reference `table.x` using `table.x` was made, what could cause that to, and or why would that, throw an exception?

Comment: I believe that nothing would cause that to throw an exception. This must have been an error in my code or structure. Thanks Marc I am accepting this answer.

Comment: aliases exist only at the query level. `select table1.x AS abc, table2.abc` is not an error, because 'abc' and 'table2.abc' are two completely different things, but trying to use just `abc` later on would be ambiguous.

Comment: I think you misunderstood because it looks like I only mentioned `table.x` when I meant `table1.x`. Anyhow, I have come across an exception being thrown when trying to access `table1.x` when `table1.x AS abc` is defined. If this is a result of bad code in the mysql connector, or as a result of a something which has been changed locally in trying to fix a bug is uncertain. (see more here if interested: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67183&thanks=2&notify=7 ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its pretty much like renaming the columns while selecting. Outside the `select` query the columns should be referred using aliases but with-in the select query, you should use table column e.g. below:

```
  select col1 as a
  from table b
  where col1 = 'xxx';
```

but outside select query, alias should be use:

```
select a 
from (select col1 AS a From table) b
where a = 'xxxx';
```

If you attempt to use the table column, it will fail:

```
<<----FAILURE -->
select col1 
from (select col1 AS a From table) b
where a = 'xxxx';
```